# Is a pointed cone always acute?

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-cone

how to show ?

A cone C is called acute, if there exists an open halfspace$ Ha = \{x ∈ R^P :
\langle x, a \rangle  > 0\} $  such that $cl(C) ⊂ Ha ∪{0}$.

Is a pointed cone always acute? What
about a convex cone?

A subset$ C ⊆ R^P$ is called a cone, if $αd ∈ C $for all $d ∈ C$
and for all α ∈ R, α > 0.

A cone C in $ R^P $is called

• convex if $αd1 + (1 − α)d2 \in C $for all $d1, d2 \in C $and for all $0 < α < 1$

• pointed if for $d \in C, d\neq 0, −d \neq C, i.e., C ∩ (−C) ⊆ {0}$

$cl(S) = int(S) ∪ bd(S)$  is the closure of S

$int(S)$ is the interior of $S $ and  $ bd(S)$ is the boundary of $S $

$\langle x, a \rangle$  is Interior product.

I'm having trouble for solving the exercises of multicriteria optimization m.ehgrott  .Or there is a book that can be helpful for better understanding?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim.** A pointed cone need not be acute.

*Proof.* Consider $\Bbb R^2$ and $C=\{\,\alpha u\mid 0<\alpha, u\in\{(1,0),(0,1),(-1,-1)\}\,\}$. $\square$

---

In fact, we even have

**Claim.** A convex pointed cone need not be acute.

*Proof.*
Consider $\Bbb R^2$ and $C=\{\,(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x> 0\,\}$. $\square$

Comment: In your first example, the condition should be $\alpha \geq 0$.  The origin is in the cone.

Comment: In the second example, the origin is also in $C$.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen thanks alot

Comment: May I ask you a question @Hagen von Eitzen? If a cone is convex then is it a accute cone? I mean a cone needs not to be pointed.